# Excel Filters - show only relevant values in the filter

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Lets say i have two filters in an excel pivot table.

Both would initially display all values in the selected range for the filter column.

When i select a couple of values only in filter 1, the filter 2 still continues to display all values in that's particular filter's column in the selected range in base data.

What i want to do is when a certain value is selected in one filter, the second filter automatically reloads to show only values relevant to the values selected in filter 1.

Any help or workaround would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to to click right mouse on the table and choose PivotTable options,
then go to 'Data' tab, and then choose 'None' under: Number of items to retain per field.
i think this should solve the problem.

Comment: It's been a long time but thanks for the answer. This will unfortunately require me to manually intervene every time there is a change in selection which i did not want. And there are like 10 filters so it also becomes very impractical for the user. I ended up writing custom controls using macros with drop-downs and hid the pivot filters. The custom controls worked just fine. But an inbuilt support to achieve this would really have saved me 4 days of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Adding slicers instead of normal dropdown filters solves this problem. Because in slicers non-available options are greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the slicer, select 'slicer settings' choose 'hide items with no data'